# Converting ArrayList of bytes to byte[]

Tags: java

I'm looking to convert an ArrayList of bytes to byte[] in order to create a file with these bytes later. I've searched high and low on how to do this but still cant get my head around it. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as an `ArrayList<byte>`. When you declare one, you get an `ArrayList<Byte>`. So there's no single function idiom for turning this into `byte[]`. You'll have to allocate the `byte[]` and then write a loop to copy the values.

Or, you could use the fastutil library which does have a container like `ArrayList` that stores `byte` and which can yield an array.

Comment: Its also incredibly inefficient to have an ArrayList[Byte] compared to a byte[]. Each element has an object pointer (4-8 bytes) + the Byte object overhead(12bytes) + the actual byte for the data. You really want to avoid this especially with a big array. This is how 40MB of data becomes 840MB in memory.

Comment: after further research I have found the following... http://codeglobe.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/convert-object-to-byte-array-using-java.html would this solve my problem?

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayList<Byte> in = ...;
int n = in.size();
byte[] out = new byte[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  out[i] = in.get(i);
}
```

I don't think the standard library provides any shortcuts for the above, provided you need `byte[]` and not `Byte[]`.

Comment: When I try and use this I get an imcompatible types error on the second from bottom line. required byte, Object found.

Comment: @user1286779 Only if you didn't copy the first line correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29), it's just [`Bytes.toArray(byteList)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29).  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Answer (score 1):

The function toArray should work, I don't hav ethe possibility to test it though..

```
    ArrayList<Byte> listArray = new ArrayList<Byte>();

    listArray.add((byte)1);
    listArray.add((byte)2);
    listArray.add((byte)3);

    Byte[] myArray = new Byte[3];
    listArray.toArray(myArray);
```

I don't know if the [boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) would be a problem for you though, if you want to use it when writing to a file.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for Byte[], but rather byte[].