# Get Byte from JSON

Tags: java, json

I have a Byte array being returned in my `JSON`.

**JSON**

`[{"template":167,255,1,30,179,0,218,0,2,88,1,184,0],
"template2":null,
"template3":null,
"Client_Id":1160739}]`

In Java, how can I recover this byte array ?

I try return a String in `JSON` instead the byte array, but when I convert to byte, it will change the value that I need. Example, 167 is the value that I need because this is already the byte value, but if I try to convert 167 to byte, it will return another value, so I need recover it as byte value.

**JAVA**

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> vetor = ArrayJson(client);
byte[] template = (byte[])vetor.get(0).get("template");
```

I'm using the [json.org/java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) repository to construct the json helper class.

Comment: There's no built in JSON parser in Java. Are you using a library? Which one? (Don't reply in a comment - edit the question)

Comment: do you have control over the json producer?

Comment: @epoch Yes I have. Has some idea to change something ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java byte array contains negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609394/java-byte-array-contains-negative-numbers)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10667402/1183010

Comment: @Lucas_Santos, convert your byte array to base64 in your producer, it is better as a serialized format

Comment: @epoch I do that, but it return something like `"template":"p/8BHrMA2gACWAG4AMcAAk"` how can I recover that ?

Comment: well, just decode it again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `byte` data type is good for 256 different numbers - yet, in java, when you use bytes, they are interpreted as signed two's complement numbers. This is most likely what happens to you. Note that the bit pattern is not changed, only the output changes.

You can recover the unsigned value in byte `b` with `(b & 0xff)`

Answer (score 0):

JSON has no concept of bytes, so what you have is an array of numbers.
You can just iterate over them and build up a byte array by casting each of the numbers to `byte`.

Suppose you got your array of numbers into a `int[]` array using a JSON library of choice, simply do this:

```
int[] numbers = ...
byte[] bytes = new byte[numbers.length];
for (int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++) {
    bytes[i] = (byte)numbers[i];
}
```

Comment: This will produce different values for each element that exist in my byte array

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:
The Classes are present in `org.json` package.

```
String jsonString = "{'template':[167,255,1,30,17,1,204,0,1,237,0,128,0] }";

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("template");
byte[] array = new byte[jArray.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    array[i] = (byte)jArray.getInt(i);
}
```

Comment: This will return negative values, like in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609394/java-byte-array-contains-negative-numbers` I need e
exactly the numbers that are returned is this array, because they are already the byte value

Comment: @Lucas_Santos As I told in my answer: there is no way to get i.e. 204 out of a byte, unless you properly mask the value, as the conversion to int extends the sign. If you need 204 and are concerned about some "negative" numbers when printing, **don't use bytes**.